# Create Office 365 groups using client library programatically

Tags: office365, office365-restapi

I am trying to create Office 365 groups programatically. I found that there is one possible way to create Office 365 groups via REST API through Graph. I read that there will be Client Library for creating Office 365 groups, but I couldn't find much information. Does anyone created Office 365 groups using Client library. Please suggest.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Microsoft.Graph Nuget Package.

Then, you can use the GraphServiceClient to create the service.
Next, you simply use the client to pull whatever you need down.

```
GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(Iauthcontext provider or proxy);
var me = client.me.request().getasync();
```

The hard work is in setting up the Authenticator, but if you search the we for samples with the GraphServiceClient, you will find many.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new group using the Client Side API (CSOM) should be something like this.

```
 GroupCreationInformation info = new GroupCreationInformation();
 info.Title = "My new group";
 Group grp = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups.Add(info);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

If you use [OfficeDev PnP](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP) you will have an easier life since they it adds a bunch of extension methods like the following

```
clientContext.Web.AddGroup("My new group", "", true, true);
```